# How to determine the human-readable type of a cv::Mat?

Tags: opencv

My current problem is that I would like to know the type of the `cv::Mat`-frames grabbed by `cv::VideoCapture` from a video file. The documentation doesn't specify that (as is often the case, so even if I have overlooked it in this particular case, it would still be helpful to get an answer for dealing with the problem in general).

Of course, I could open the appropriate OpenCV header file and go through the `CV_64FC2`, ... macros to find a macro which matches the Mat's `type()`. But I'm kind of sick of that. There must be an easier way.

Isn't there any function that lets me translate a Mat's `type()` to a human-readable format ? Like this:

```c
cv::Mat myMatWithUnknownType;

// Some code modifying myMatWithUnknownType.
// ...

std::string readableType = myMatWithUnknownType.typeString();
std::cout << readableType; // Prints "CV_64FC3".
```

How do you deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

First, the format that come from cameras is only one: `CV_8UC3`. This is hardcoded in OpenCV, and any video format is converted to this before being sent to user. So

```
capture >> frame;
```

Will always return a RGB image, of 8 bits per channel.

Now, for other types you can write your function, keeping in mid that there are not so many types supported in OpenCV: A Mat can be of type `char`, `uchar`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `float`, `double`, of 1 to 512 channels (according to the latest docs.) So writing your own `type_to_string()` is not difficult.